# Creating and submitting a new post in Flask keeps redirecting me to wrong URL, leading to 404

Tags: flask, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create my own website using Flask. The project structure currently looks like this:

```
.
└── my-website/
    ├── my_website/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── app.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── routes.py
    │   └── blog_posts.db
    ├── templates/
    │   ├── home.html
    │   ├── posts.html
    │   ├── new_post.html
    │   └── post.html
    ├── static/
    │   └── style.css
    ├── tests/
    └── .envrc
```

The content of `app.py` is as follows:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from .models import db, Post
from .routes import post_pages


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Configure the SQLite database and start the ORM
    base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    db_name = os.path.join(base_dir, "blog_posts.db")
    db_path = f"sqlite:///{db_name}"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = db_path

    db.init_app(app)

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.register_blueprint(post_pages)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')

    @app.route('/posts')
    def posts():
        post_list = Post.query.all()
        return render_template('posts.html', posts=post_list)

    return app


app = create_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        debug=True,
    )
```

And `routes.py` and `models.py` each look like the following:

```
# models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Post(db.Model):
    id_ = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

```
# routes.py
import logging

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from .models import db, Post


post_pages = Blueprint("posts", __name__)
logger = logging.getLogger()


@post_pages.route("/post/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form.get("title")
        content = request.form.get("content")
        new_post = Post(title=title, content=content)

        logger.info(new_post)

        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(
            url_for("posts.display_post", title=new_post.title)
        )

    return render_template("new_post.html")


@post_pages.get("/posts/<string:title>")
def display_post(title):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first_or_404()

    return render_template(
        "post.html",
        title=post.title,
        content=post.content,
    )
```

Whenever I run the app and go to `localhost:5000/post`, I get a form that allows me to input the title and content of the blog post. My understanding is that after I hit "Submit" in that form, the website should redirect me to `localhost:5000/posts/<title>`. However, the website redirects me to `localhost:5000/posts` and shows me a "Not Found" error.

I've tried modifying the directory names in the decorators, but I keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong right now?

### Edit

*The following are the HTML files that I'm using.*

#### `posts.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('posts') }}">Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <body>
        <h1 id="posts-page-title">All Posts</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `new_post.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Create Post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Create a new post</h1>
        <form action="/posts/" method="post">
            <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
            <label for="content">Content:</label><br>
            <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('posts') }}">Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <body>
        <h1 id="home-welcome-message">Welcome!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `post.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <article>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
    </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML/JS for `new_post.html`? Would be helpful to see how you're handling the form data

Comment: @Rob Sure. I'll edit it into the OP.

Comment: I think you might just be able to change the return statement in `create_post` from `return redirect(url_for("posts.display_post", title=new_post.title) )` to `return redirect(f'posts/{new_post.title}')`

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately that didn't work. `redirect(f"posts/{new_post.title}")` nor `redirect(url_for(f"posts/{new_post.title}"))` seem to work. :(

Comment: Could you try and add to your function `print(new_post.title)`  and tell me if the output?

Comment: Ope, sorry I forgot to put a `/` in front - try `return redirect(f'/posts/{new_post.title}')`. That should at least direct you to the correct URL, right?

Comment: @NoNameAv Well, there is nothing being printed out to stdout. I'm assuming that there may be an error in the new post if that's the case. @Rob That didn't work either... :( I'll try and take a look at how `new_post` is being handled/created.

Comment: I think it may be a database problem. When I open my `blog_posts.db` file via `sqlite3 blog_posts.db` and check if there are any tables or anything, there doesn't seem to be anything there.